# When to update JWT access token with refresh token

Tags: authentication, jwt, token, access-token, quasar-framework

I made a Quasar App with an external authentification server. After the login I receive the access and refresh token. The refresh token is not expiring until I press logout. The access token expires after 10 minutes. So since I need the access token to get the data, this is possible for the next 10 minutes after login. Afterwards I have to call an API including the refresh token to get a new access token.
My question is, how can I make sure to always have a valid access token without logging in again?

As a User I expect to login and have access to everything until I logout. And if my App was for example 15 minutes just laying around and then I want to receive data, that's not possible.

Somehow I want to call the refresh token api silently, but when and how?
Is it common to refresh the token at a certain time interval, or on changing a page or every time I want to receive data?
I didn't find an efficient solution yet.

In a boot file I added the refresh token method. So every time the App was started, the token will be refreshed. For iPhone users for example the app won't be closed completely so the init-method will not be triggered until I completely close the App manually.

I guess to refresh the token before every API call is too much. Or is it?

Comment: in your axios boot file, you can just check if token exist, expire datetime, ...

If your access_token is expired, call your refresh token method, get new access token ...

we can imagine a 

```js
axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
    const store = securityStore() 
    const isLoggedIn = store?.jwt;
   const expire = store.?expire
expire > new Date() ? store.useRefreshToken().then(()=>{

return config
})
```

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, how can I make sure to always have a valid access
> token without logging in again?

You may use Axios response interceptors in the Quasar Axios boot file to check if a response has failed due to expired access token (based on status code eg 401).

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return res;
  },
  async(error) => {
    if (error.response) {
      if (error.response.status === 401) {
        // Use refresh token here to get new JWT token;
        // return a request
        return axios_instance(config);
      }
    }

    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Hope this helps!